# How to join two dataframes in JS with data-forge?

Tags: javascript, data-manipulation, data-forge

I'm trying to use [`data-forge`](https://github.com/data-forge/data-forge-ts/blob/master/docs/guide.md#join) to join two dataframes, but I'm getting an empty merged dataframe:

```
const a = new DataFrame([{ A: 10, b: 1 }, { A: 20, b: 2 }, { A: 30, b: 3 }]);
const b = new DataFrame([{ A: 10, c:11 }, { A: 20, c:22 }, { A: 30, c:33 }]);
const ab = a.join(
  b,
  left => left.A,
  right => right.A,
  (left, right) => {
    return { A: left.A, b: left.b, c: right.c };
  }
);
// {content: null}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your join is working as intended. I suspect the reason your are getting `{content: null}` is that your are `console.log`ging `ab`, but due to `data-forge`'s lazy evaluation, it hasn't resolved the content. If you use the [`.toString()`](https://data-forge.github.io/data-forge-ts/classes/dataframe.html#tostring) method, it forces lazy evaluation to complete. Try this:

```
    const a = new dataForge.DataFrame([
      { A: 10, b: 1 },
      { A: 20, b: 2 },
      { A: 30, b: 3 },
    ]);
    const b = new dataForge.DataFrame([
      { A: 10, c: 11 },
      { A: 20, c: 22 },
      { A: 30, c: 33 },
    ]);
    const ab = a.join(
      b,
      (left) => left.A,
      (right) => right.A,
      (left, right) => {
        return { A: left.A, b: left.b, c: right.c };
      },
    );

    console.log(ab);
    // DataFrame { configFn: [Function], content: null }
    console.log(ab.toString());
    // __index__  A   b  c
    // ---------  --  -  --
    // 0          10  1  11
    // 1          20  2  22
    // 2          30  3  33
```